# set tds to fill entire row depending on number of tr

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tr element within a table that has a fixed width, how do I ensure that all the td elements combined fill up the entire row, depending on how many tds there are.

Ie if there are 4 cells they each take up 25%, 3 cells they each take up 33% etc

Comment: Width or colspan options in td should solve it. You can use width percentages as you mentioned. Or the older way is to use colspan. There is also another way to use divs as a substitute for columns along with column-width option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may add CSS to your `tds` by accessing them via JS.

like, you may add class names to td. In your HTML

```
<td class="data-cells">Data</td>
```

and in JS

```
const elms = document.documentsGetElementsByClassName("data-cells");
elms.forEach(function(td){
   if(cells === 4) {
      td.classList.add('four_col_layout');
   } else if () {
      td.classList.add('three_col_layout');
   }
})
```

In your CSS

```
.three_col_layout {
  width:33.33333%;
}

.four_col_layout {
  width:25%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a way to automatically calculate it, the way you can set the width of a row to 100%

Comment: I think the javascript part helps since you css is only for styling where you define styles, you can define the style of an element level using javascript I guess then calculate the answer

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to what @Dalvik posted, a way might be to style using javascript and classes

> Data

and then set width property to 100% / row.cells.length;